# Trying to subtract value, which was retrieved from file

Tags: python, arrays, file, object, integer

I am trying to simply try to change the account value of a specific account through the parameter y being the value being subtracted. I am not sure why there is an error as the values stored should be correct but the error consists.

error:

```
File "main.py", line 64, in withdraw
    if int(d.acc) >= int(y):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

```
allCustom = []
class Customer: 
    def __init__(self, name, date, address, hkid, acc):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
        self.address = address
        self.hkid = hkid
        self.acc = acc

allf = open("CustomInfo.txt","r")
every_acc = allf.readlines()
for c in range (1, len(every_acc), 6):
    update= every_acc[c].replace("Name:","").strip()
    update2= every_acc[c+1].replace("Birth Date:","").strip()
    update3= every_acc[c+2].replace("Address:","").strip()
    update4= every_acc[c+3].replace("HKID:","").strip()
    update5 = every_acc[c+4].replace("Account value:","").strip()
    allCustom.append (Customer(update, update2,update3,update4,update5))
allf.close()
def withdraw (x,y):
    global allCustom
    count = 0
    for d in allCustom:
        if d.hkid== x:
            if int(d.acc) >= int(y):
                allCustom[count] = Customer (d.name, d.date, d.address, d.hkid, str(int(d.acc)-int(y)))
                print("Success! Please collect your money.")
                break
            else:
                print("Sorry but you have inseffecient funds to withdraw $"+y)
        elif count == len(allCustom):
            print("Your HKID does not match any account in our database. Returning to starting screen")
        else:
            count +=1
```

Here is the text file:

```
Name:Jose Gamez
Birth Date:7/20/2002
Address:Hong Kong, Tung Chung, Yun Tung, Block 33, Floor 10, Flat 9
HKID:C1357434
Account value:2234

Name:Viraj Ghuman
Birth Date:7/20/2002
Address:Hong Kong, Heng Fa Chuen, 100 Shing Tai Road, Block 22, Floor 20, Flat 1
HKID:C6969689
Account value:100000
```

Comment: what is the input you tried and also the complete content of the file?

Comment: also, if you don't have the file headers, the loop should be iterating from `0` as `range(0, len(every_acc), 6`

Comment: the input x is the HKID so it can find the account value for that HKID such as C1357434. And I believe I don't have file headers.

Comment: you should get the errors `update5 = every_acc[c+4].replace("Account value:","").strip()
;IndexError: list index out of range` if there are no headers with the current code

Comment: That's weird I actually didn't get any error like that.

Comment: if you could the input file and the input you tried at some hosted location (pastebin.com), I could try to have a look.

Comment: pastebin.com/tvp0E8Wc is this what you mean?

Comment: yes, @justadude619, were you able to resolve the issue or still need help?

Answer (score 1):

Some of your accounts seem to have an empty account value, and you can't cast an empty value to int. Maybe check this in your code :)

Comment: Wait but in my txt file, all of the account values are above 0.

Comment: @justadude619 Python arrays start at 0, just replace 1 by 0 in your for loop and it should work. Your code on, pastebin worked for me : `for c in range (0, len(every_acc), 6):`

I guess the empty values in your account came from the empty lines in your file ;)

Comment: I get what you mean but the first line of my text file is blank that's why I started at 1.